# A remarkable almost-identity

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences, polylogarithms

[OEIS sequence A210247](https://oeis.org/A210247) gives the signs of  $\text{li}(-n,-1/3) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k k^n/3^k$, also the signs of the Maclaurin coefficients of $4/(3 + \exp(4x))$.

Mikhail Kurkov noticed that it appeared that $a(n+28) = -a(n)$ for this sequence.
It's not quite true: the first $n$'s for which this is not true are $578, 1143,$ and $1736$.  But still it's remarkably close to true.

A nice illustration of the [Strong Law of Small Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers)?  Is there any explanation for the almost-identity, or is it just coincidence?  Is it still true for large $n$ that $a(n+28)$ is usually $-a(n)$?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Consider $F(z) = 4/(3+\exp(4z))$ as a function of the complex variable $z$.  It is meromorphic and has simple poles where the denominator vanishes.  Namely when $4z = \log 3 + (2k +1)\pi i$ for integers $k$.   The poles with the smallest magnitude of $z$ occur when $4z = \log 3 \pm \pi i$.  We can compute the Taylor series coefficients of $F$ by looking at 
$$ 
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|= r} F(z) z^{-n} \frac{dz}{z},
$$ 
starting with $r$ suitably small.  Now we can estimate the integral asymptotically by taking larger values of $r$, and accounting for poles that are encountered.  As noted above, the smallest poles are at $(\log 3 \pm \pi i)/4$ and these will account for the leading asymptotics of these coefficients.  Now, the argument of $(\log 3 \pm \pi i)/4$ is  $\pm 1.23438\ldots $ which is very nearly $11 \pi/28=1.23419\ldots$.  This accounts for the observed phenomenon.

Comment: Out of curiosity: does it answer the question that for large $n$ that $a(n+28)$ is usually $-a(n)$?

Comment: @Andrew:  Yes, for large $n$ most of the time the signs will flip, but a small proportion of the time it won't.   The answer roughly says that the signs look like the signs of $\cos (1.23438 n)$ (not being too careful here), which will have the similar feature of flipping very often when $n$ is increased by $28$.

Comment: I just asked WolframAlpha.  It's surely no big deal to compute $\arctan (\pi/(4\log 3))$.